# Disable iPad Chrome autocomplete bar

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I observed this bar with autocomplete options on my iPad on Chrome and hiding textarea. Textarea is on the very bottom of the page.

I tried `autocomplete="chat-content"`, but doesn't work.

Is there any way to disable this bar to show for all users?

[image: Unnecessary bar]